# Анимационный переход от одной Активити к другой с помощью таймера

Tags: android, activity

У меня 2 Активити. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы по истечению двух секунд первый активити вверх медленно поднималось, а второй активити без никакой анимации появился на экране. Проблема в том что я сделал анимацию, она работает если по клику. А по таймеру если ставить то второй активити открывается только без анимации... Как правильно это сделать?

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
       public void run() {
           startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this,   ContentActivity.class));
           Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this,
                ContentActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);

           transitionType = TransitionType.SlideLeft;
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_two, R.anim.slide_one);
           finish();
       }
   }, 2000);
```